# Consulta SQL com WITH para agrupar

Tags: oracle

o que deveria mudar em minha consulta

```
WITH Consulta AS
  (SELECT DT_RFRN_MVMN,
    TX_DATA_VNDA,
    CD_BNDR,
    CD_CRDE,
    CD_PCSR CD_EMSR,
    CD_TIPO_PLTF_PGMN,
    CD_TIPO_TRNS_BNDR_RECB,
    CD_TIPO_APRS_TRNS_RECB,
    CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB,
    numerolinha= row_number() over (partition BY CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB order by CD_CRDE DESC)
  FROM CLC.TBCLCR_LNCM_RECB
  )
SELECT DT_RFRN_MVMN,
  TX_DATA_VNDA,
  CD_BNDR,
  CD_CRDE,
  CD_PCSR CD_EMSR,
  CD_TIPO_PLTF_PGMN,
  CD_TIPO_TRNS_BNDR_RECB,
  CD_TIPO_APRS_TRNS_RECB,
  CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB
FROM Consulta
WHERE numerolinha = 1;
```

Para trazer o resultado agrupado por CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Consulta AS
  (SELECT DT_RFRN_MVMN,
    TX_DATA_VNDA,
    CD_BNDR,
    CD_CRDE,
    CD_PCSR CD_EMSR,
    CD_TIPO_PLTF_PGMN,
    CD_TIPO_TRNS_BNDR_RECB,
    CD_TIPO_APRS_TRNS_RECB,
    CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB,
    numerolinha= row_number() over (partition BY CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB order by CD_CRDE DESC)
  FROM CLC.TBCLCR_LNCM_RECB
  )
SELECT DT_RFRN_MVMN,
  TX_DATA_VNDA,
  CD_BNDR,
  CD_CRDE,
  CD_PCSR CD_EMSR,
  CD_TIPO_PLTF_PGMN,
  CD_TIPO_TRNS_BNDR_RECB,
  CD_TIPO_APRS_TRNS_RECB,
  CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB
FROM Consulta
WHERE numerolinha = 1
GROUP BY CD_PRDT_BNDR_RECB;
```